Netdata disable module configured alarm
I have a netdata alarm that I would like to disable. I specifically think I have an edge case that makes this alarm trigger even when it's not useful in our case.
Unfortunately, looking at the configuration, the PostgreSQL module seems to be all or nothing when it comes to alarms. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing here are is there somewhere else in the product that would let me disable or configure this particular alarm in some way?
